# how can i find the Box ios sdk version?

Tags: ios, objective-c, box-api

I applied ios box sdk long time ago. but I do not know sdk version.

and I want to update sdk, if there is some changes. but

https://developer.box.com/

this site does not have any change log or current version information.

question :

1. How to know sdk version in my app.
2. how to know sdk change log(deprecated api..)

Answer (score 0):

If you installed the Box iOS SDK using CocoaPods, you can [look at your Podfile.lock file](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html#what-is-podfilelock) to see what version you are using.